# В устройстве нет диска. GCC

Tags: mingw, компилятор

Работало все нормально, но вдруг при вызове gcc стало выбивать ошибку **В устройстве нет диска. Вставьте диск в устройство Е:**

Точно сказать не могу, после чего это произошло. Была установлена, кажется, только Visual Studio Code. Переустановка MinGW не помогла. Пока что-то помогает отключение устройства в диспетчере

Comment: Скорее всего это какая-то проблема с железом (м.б. контакты?)

Comment: даже не знаю с чем связано, но флеш накопители нормально работают

Comment: а в переменных окружения, которое формируется для запуска процесса gcc, не присутствует упоминаний про «устройство» `e:`? // и уточните, пожалуйста: вы именно программу gcc запускаете, или какую-то другую программу (make, например), которая **вызывает** gcc?

Comment: нет, ничего о `E:` нет. В любом случае, хоть то через make, хоть через   командную строку, при любых параметрах

Comment: Т.е. Вы набираете в командной строке `gcc` и вместо `gcc: no input files` видите свое сообщение об E: ?

Comment: не совсем, сообщение вылазит в MessageBox, и после закрытия где-то третьего такого бокса в консоли выводится `gcc: no input files`

Comment: Ну, значит gcc тут скорее всего ни при чем. А что у Вас с антивирусом?

Comment: ESS, никаких изменений в работе чего либо другого не замечаю